# JQuery click function not working on a particular item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Bjf7c/1/ and explain why the on click function does not work after we select another item and return back to the first selected item. It looks something weird to me since all the similar items fires the click function but not for the default selected item.

In the example first click on F and then click on E. You will find that all other items are clickable except E.

```
$(".items.cursor:not('.selected')").on('click',function(){   
    $('.items.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

When you write

```
$(".items.cursor:not('.selected')").on('click',function(){
```

you bind your event handler to all items that are not selected **at time of binding**, not at time of click. So you don't bind to your initially selected element.

You could use `on` and delegation to keep your selector and have it tested each time but here is a better solution :

```
$(".items.cursor").on('click',function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) return;
  $('.items.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

(in this specific example the test isn't really useful but it might be if you add more code and don't want it to be executed if the user clicks the already selected element)

Comment: That works!! Thanks a lot for the solution plus its explanation

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a function on the click event only to the non selected elements.
E is selected when the page loads and you bind this function.